# How do I index my Blogger post on Google using Google API Indexing?

Tags: blogger, google-indexing-api

I used many methods like through google cloud adn create api id and then via google collab but did'nt get any solution iwth which I can index my blogger post instantly.

I tried many methods as mentioned, Anybody help me with this